# Login aliases for smtp/imap?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a user account on my system, "backup_account", which is an alias for backup@example.com. I can't use the simpler account name, "backup", because a system user (uid: 34) already exists on the server with that name.

To make things less confusing, I'd like to allow the user to log into imap/smtp with the user name "backup" instead of "backup_account".

Is this possible? How do I accomplish this? I'm running postfix and dovecot.

Answer (score 1):

I've pieced together a solution from a couple of different sources. Your solution may very depending on what kind of auth you're using. But for me, using system users, the steps are:

1. Edit `/etc/dovecot/auth-system.conf.ext` (this file is included by `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` in my dovecot config, so you may need to edit a different file depending on which one is included).
2. Add the following stanza before the current `passdb` stanza:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = /etc/dovecot/aliases
}
```

3. Create the dovecot aliases file at /etc/dovecot/aliases and add the following:

`backup:::::::user=backup_account noauthenticate`

Obviously, you'll need to change `backup` and `backup_account` to your own account names.

4. Restart dovecot with `sudo systemctl dovecot restart`